# CSS: aligning image in image slider issues

Tags: css

I'm trying to learn how to make various image sliders and the issue I'm running into is, I can not figure out how to align my image within my "image slider" properly.

I've tried numerous things and I'm just not understanding how to accomplish this.

The main div has a black bg color, the image slider div has a red bg color so i can see alignment. I've got the image slider centered and such but I can not get the image to center in the image slider itself. It sits uncentered on to the right currently.

https://jsfiddle.net/5gn40f3z/2/

**HTML**

```
<div id="sliderContainer">
    <div id="slideWrapper">
        <ul id="slide">
            <li><img src="https://placeimg.com/800/300/any"></li>
            <li><img src="https://placehold.it/800x300"></li>
            <li><img src="https://placehold.it/800x300"></li>
            <li><img src="https://placehold.it/800x300"></li>
            <li><img src="https://placehold.it/800x300"></li>
        </ul>
        <span class="slideNav" id="previous"></span>
        <span class="slideNav" id="next"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#sliderContainer{
    background-color: black;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#slideWrapper{
    background-color: red;
    width: 800px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#slideWrapper li{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    maring: 0 auto;
}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the following CSS rules:

```
#sliderContainer {
  font-size: 0;
}
#slide {
  padding: 0;
}
```

[**Demo on JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/5gn40f3z/3/).

- `font-size: 0` on container to eliminate offset from the top. It appears due to whitespaces in your HTML code. If those whitespaces will have height `0`, they won't cause you trouble.
- `padding: 0` on your `<ul>` to eliminate offset from the left. `<ul>` is by default given a particular padding by most browsers More at [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ul.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Your `<ul id="slide">` tag still has a left padding defined in user agent styles. You need to reset it.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will solve your problem, if you choose div.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
         ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```